# ng-repeat for an array represented by a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to use ng-repeat to display an array. Depending on the value of a variable, the array ng-repeat loops through should change.

Here is what I have done so far (which doesn't work)

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h1 ng-repeat="x in selection">{{x}}</h1>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records1 = [
    "Apple",
    "Orange",
    "Banana",
    "Mango",
  ];
  $scope.records2 = [
     "Lion",
     "Tiger",
     "Crocodile",
     "Olephant"
  ];
  $scope.selection = records1;

});
```

What am I doing wrong here and what is the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should do this:

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records1 = [
    "Apple",
    "Orange",
    "Banana",
    "Mango",
  ];
  $scope.records2 = [
     "Lion",
     "Tiger",
     "Crocodile",
     "Olephant"
  ];
  $scope.selection = $scope.records1;

});
```

Comment: The selection shows the array you are settiing. If you set $scop.records1, it shows the values of records1 and so on records2. What would you want to acomplish. I think I can't follow your requirement